# Recognize specific ringtone

Tags: audio, raspberry-pi

What I want is to be able to get a signal at my raspberry pi at home when I'm not at home so I can e.g. wake up my PC. I always have an old phone lying around that I never really use. So I thought, I can call my phone, a specific mp3 ringtone plays, my raspberry pi listens and recognizes the ringtone and therefore the signal. So I can pretty much chose whatever ringtone I want (but hopefully a not too long one). But the problem is, that it should be recognizable by the raspberry and it should be distinguishable from other sounds. At best I can play random music at home and it will not get signalled until it's the specific ringtone i chose.
So I'm at the very beginning of the project and I have a lot of question. Is this even feasible? How do I listen to the ringtone? Should I use a normal microphone or could I e.g. trigger some gpio pin as long as a specific frequency is played? What kind of ringtone should I use to be as distinguishable as possible? And how to create the software to recognize the sound?

I know this is a lot and I don't expect a step by step solution. But maybe you got some hints to get me in the right direction?

Comment: IMHO, you might find it considerably easier to make your phone vibrate instead of ringing and then detect the vibration https://www.instructables.com/Vibration-Sensor-SW-420-Raspberry-Pi/

Answer (score 1):

If someone has a similar problem, I found a solution: First I had to choose between a mostly hardware solution and a mostly software solution. The hardware solution is to filter specific frequencies. This seems to be pretty hard using normal band-pass filters if you want narrow bands. There are also components that can do that, now I know of the NE567. But this component only reacts to one frequency and takes quite a lot of energy. To recognize a ringtone, more of these components are needes which means more power consumption. Additionally this solution is pretty unflexible.

So I went for the software solution. Now I have an Arduino Uno that gets an amplified electret microphone signal at an analog input pin. The data is collected and simultaneously analysed with an FFT algorithm. Then I check the dominant frequency if there is any and safe it in an array. Everytime a got a new data point I compare the array with the pattern of my ringtone and calculate a score for the match. If the score is big enough the ringtone is "found" and I can trigger my event.

I'm actually pretty pleased with the solution because it works quite well even with the phone some feet away from the microphone. I thought I need to put the microphone almost directly next to the phone to get good results, but I dont have to. It's still a little sensitive, because the sound volume shouldnt be too high or to low. But with the right volume settings it works with a quite big area when the phone is in the same room. It works even better with some space between microphone and phone, because the phones radiation from the call seems to disturb the circuit quite a lot. There is also the problem, that other noises block the ringtone recognition. I could compensate that with my algorithm, but I almost used up all resources of the Arduino, so I had to keep the algorithm simple. But in my case I dont have a noisy environment, so this is not a problem for me. Another pro is that my event was never triggered from another sound and it seems almost impossible that this could happen by accident.

So it is feasible and I think its actually a quite elegant solution. I also thought about a vibration detection or even directly using the vibration motor's signal but I have no control over the vibration function of that old phone. But I can chose the ringtone for every contact, so I only gave the "magic" ringtone to myself and so the event can only be triggered by myself. I only have to say, that writing the software was kind of hard with the Arduinos limitations. Because I need the data in real time I have limited time for the calculation. I had to limit the incomping data and therefore I can only listen to frequencies up to 10kHz. But the ringtone recognition is still possible and I think it was worth the effort. :)